# Random number generator game in PHP using a form

Tags: php, html, forms, random

I am trying to create a webpage that prompts the user to guess a number from 1 to 5 which is randomly generated and stored in the form.

Then, when the form is submitted, the guess is checked against the random number and if the guess is incorrect, the user is prompted to guess again but the random value stays the same with each guess.

My issue is that once the user submits the form, the random number is not showing up when the user is prompted to try again.

```
else if (isset($_POST["firstname"])) {
    echo $_POST['firstname'] . $_POST['lastname'];
    echo "Hi " . $_POST['firstname'] . " " . $_POST['lastname'] . "!";
    ?>
    <html>
        <form name="number" action="random.php" method="post">
            <p>Enter a guess: <input type="text" name="guess" /></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="numtobeguessed" value="<?php echo $_POST["numtobeguessed"]; ?>" ></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Guess!" />
        </form>
    </html>
    <?php
    $_POST["numtobeguessed"] = rand(1, 5);
    $guessed = $_POST["numtobeguessed"];
    echo "Number to be guessed " . $guessed;

} else if (isset($_POST["guess"])) {
    if ($_POST["guess"] != $_POST["guessed"]) {
        echo $_POST["guess"] . " is not correct";
        ?>
        <form name="number1" action="random.php" method="post">
            <p>Enter a guess: <input type="text" name="guess" /></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="numtobeguessed" value="<?php echo $_POST["guessed"]; ?>" ></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Guess!" />
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: On a side note, I'd recommend using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. I don't know why you use both. Also, you do not need the `== true` in the `if` statements.

Comment: Are this code are for random.php?

Comment: Why do you start your code with an `else if`? Is there code before this that may be interfering?

Comment: @Jonathan There is code before this that does work. I didn't include it to save space. The code I've posted is where I'm having the issue.

Comment: Should the logic always check the `$_POST["guess"]` if it has a value? i.e when `$_POST['numtobeguessed']` has a value then the `guess` can have a value entered by the user?

Comment: On another side note, if this is all you're trying to achieve (I'm assuming it's more complex than this), I'd recommend using JS and avoid the mess of sending and receiving `$_POST` requests and refreshing the page and checking all the variables. Just use event listeners and JS to do this. It's so much easier!

Comment: I have more forms above the code listed here and the user submits the data and then in the next `if` statement, they can be accessed. For example, firstname, but for some reason when I generate the random number, it does not carry over to the next form.

Comment: can you please elaborate this question?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the value in a field with the name `numtobeguessed` but you try to read it with the name `guessed`.

This:

```
if ($_POST["guess"] != $_POST["guessed"]) {
```

should be:

```
if ($_POST["guess"] != $_POST["numtobeguessed"]) {
```

and this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numtobeguessed" value="<?php echo $_POST["guessed"]; ?>" ></p>
```

should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numtobeguessed" value="<?php echo $_POST["numtobeguessed"]; ?>" ></p>
```